# Wavesurfer.js not rendering waveform or playing

Tags: javascript, audio

I've tried a few different scripts from the github examples as well as my script:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.j
<div id="waveform"></div>

var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
container: '#waveform'
});

wavesurfer.load(hbag_100purelove.mp3);
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
wavesurfer.play();
});
```

It just won't render or play; I tested on a server and locally on Google Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it has the .js extension in my script thats a typo

Comment: You can edit the question to fix the typo - Where is the object `hbaq_100purelove` defined?

Comment: it is an mp3 in the local folder

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see - firstly I assume you have correctly referenced the external script in your actual code, but mistyped it here?  Secondly, the filename within wavesurfer.load needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>

<div id="waveform"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform'
  });

  wavesurfer.load("hbag_100purelove.mp3");
  wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I've enclosed it in quotes.I now get the cursoe but still no waveform or sound. I am sure that the file is valid. I can not fathom what my error is